# extracting facebook page from html using regex

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to get the address of a facebook page of websites using regular expression search on the html

usually the link appears as
 `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/googlechrome">Facebook</a>`

but sometimes the address will be `http://www.facebook.com/some.other`

and sometimes with numbers

at the moment the regex that I have is

```
'(facebook.com)\S\w+'
```

but it won't catch the last 2 possibilites

what is  it called when I want the regex to search but not fetch it? (for instance I want the regex to match the www.facbook.com part but not have that part in the result, only the part that comes after it

note I use python with re and urllib2

Comment: I'll post the obligatory [parse html with regexp-link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/566644).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me your main issue is that you dont understand enough regex.

```
fb_re = re.compile(r'www.facebook.com([^"]+)')
```

then simply:

```
results = fb_re.findall(url)
```

why this works:

in regular expresions the part in the parenthesis `()` is what is captured, you were putting the www.facebook.com part in the parenthesis and so it was not getting anything else.

here i used a character set `[]` to match anything in there, i used the `^` operator to negate that, which means anything not in the set, and then i gave it the `"` character, so it will match anything that comes after www.facebook.com until it reaches a `"` and then stop.

note - this catches facebook links which are embedded, if the facebook link is simply on the page in plaintext you can use:

```
fb_re = re.compile(r'www.facebook.com(\S+)')
```

which means to grab any non-white-space character, so it will stop once it runs out of white-space.

if you are worried about links ending in periods, you can simply add:

```
fb_re = re.compile(r'www.facebook.com(\S+)\.\s')
```

which tells it to search for the same above, but stop when it gets to the end of a sentence, `.` followed by any white-space like a space or enter. this way it will still grab links like `/some.other` but when you have things like `/some.other.` it will remove the last `.`

Answer (score 0):

if i assume correctly, the url is always in double quotes. right?

```
re.findall(r'"http://www.facebook.com(.+?)"',url)
```

Overall, trying to parse html with regex is a bad idea. I suggest you use an html parser like `lxml.html` to find the links and then use `urlparse`

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse # in 3.x use from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://www.facebook.com/some.other'
>>> parse_object = urlparse(url)
>>> parse_object.netloc
'facebook.com'
>>> parse_object.path
'/some.other'
```

Comment: dont need to escape the `"`. since you are using `'` as your string barriers.